# Gorm hangs on gorm.Open, no error but no response

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use gorm as an ORM for an app, but `gorm.Open` doesn't appear to ever return, which is making my app hang.  The only difference between my test case and all the examples I've seen online is my test case is connected to an AWS box, whereas all the others are connecting to local Postgres instances. Does that matter?

The code that I have is:

```
func initDB() {
    var err error
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=something.rds.amazonaws.com user=awsuser dbname=db sslmode=disable password=awspassword")
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Connected")
    defer db.Close()
}
```

I've tried switching `sslmode`, I've tried using the postgres connection string (pulled straight from a postgres client so it is valid), I've tried switching to `sql.Open`. I don't know what else there is to try. FWIW  I can see that none of my requests are hitting AWS.

Comment: Not running into firewall issues?  I could see that causing a hang.

Comment: I connect to this AWS database using PG Admin, as well as SQL-Tabs all the time, using an identical connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not in the code block I posted above, but in the `main` function that calls `initDB`. The call to `initDB` was after `http.ListenAndServe` which blocks forever.